# what is burning smell off a new power strip?

Tags: socket, cord-and-plug, surge-suppression

Got a new power strip, I detect a very faint burning smell kind of distinct when I stick my nose near it, 2 cm away. The smell is there whether it's connected or not, but amplifies when its working. I don't think that smell was there before and I've been using it for 2 weeks. The brand is Brennenstuhl, from Germany 3m long cable. It's like 20$, I connect desktop pc on it.

Answer (score 2):

Defective power strip.  Return it to the store and demand a replacement, before it causes a fire.

Comment: Has it caused damage already? Shouldn't a surge protector just allow current through, whats it doing to create a fire? Whats to say the problem is in my wall socket, and that this surge protector is more sensitive?

Comment: You should never smell smoke from a power strip. If you do, the power strip was overheating. That won't happen unless you are overloading it or it was defective -- and the circuit breaker or fuse in the power strip should have blown before an overload could hurt it. So there is an electrical problem inside the power strip, anu it should not be used in this condition. Return it if you can, discard it if you can't ... Or repair it, but if you could do that you wouldn't be asking this question.